# Wordpress - Facebook, twitter and G+ buttons in a widget?

Tags: html, wordpress

I am trying to make a widget with social buttons.  Widget, not plugin because that is too complicated.

If I have my website url as http://www.google.com, what is the code to make the buttons that will do a "like" on Facebook and twitter?

Is it possible to do with just html and no javascript?

Comment: of-cause it is possible, but for a single page not for the all posts, means paste the social networking sites codes in the `header.php` file.

Comment: I mean as a widget.  Like in the dashboard menu there is a place to add widgets.  Is there any code I can just copy and paste into there to make the buttons in HTML that will work?

Comment: noop, you have to create with your own.. or try to find some built-in widgets from the wordpress extensions..

Comment: AddThis provides a really good sharing plugin you can put on your site, and you can customise it. http://addthis.com

Comment: You can download plugins that are added to your widget menu .. Easiest thing there is :)

Answer (score 1):

You can simply do this with the following plugins:

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/addthis/

or

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/share-this/

Check both these and apply whichever is suitable for you.